# render one div and it's interactive content by clicking on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, html-rendering

```
<div id="1" class="aaa" style="position: relative; left: 50px; top: 50px; width: 300px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px; background: #dddddd; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 30px; top: 25px; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: blue;" onmouseenter="this.style.background='red';"></div>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 160px; top: 70px; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: blue;" onmouseenter="this.style.background='orange';"></div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="bbb" style="position: relative; left: 250px; top: 100px; width: 50px; height: 20px; border: solid 1px; background: #cccccc; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">click</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FWyBQ/

I have one div (id="1" class="aaa") which contains multiple interactive divs. State of this interactive content should be able to be rendered as image (gif?) with the click on the other div (id="2" class="bbb").

That image should preferably be opened in a new tab or window. Or maybe just right click > save as in place.

p.s. I am aware of scripts like html2canvas and phantomjs, but I have no idea how to implement them in my case.

**edit:**

Now I'm trying to implement [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf), which with a little tweaking should work with processing.js (http://cloud.github.com/downloads/processing-js/processing-js/processing-1.4.1.min.js).

I guess I just need the right jquery code with processing.js in order to achieve the functionality I need. I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
$('.bbb').click(function (e) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("1"),
            img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $('.aaa').document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
    });
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? Your question is unclear... :-(

Comment: to take a screenshot of the specific area on the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use html2canvas for this; include the html2canvas library in your page and try something like this:

```
  //element would be your aaa div
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        // canvas is the resulting canvas generated from the element
        var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
  });
```

You would then need to post the value of 'url'  to a PHP script like in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf).

**EDIT**

The reason your new code doesn't work is because the element with an id of "1" is not a canvas element. Its a div.

Canvas methods like toDataUrl() can only be called on Canvas elements (which is why I suggested using html2canvas to change your div into a Canvas.)

I've forked your jsfiddle to show how the code could work if the element with id "1" *was* a canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/_Pez/cksGt/1/

_Pez

Comment: I've tried to combine something (including code from html2canvas.js) without success. Now I'm trying to implement that selected solution from the link you provided - seems simple and looks like it should work. I've edited the question.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer and linked to a fiddle to show what I mean.

Comment: thanks. very simple and useful. your answer is generally correct, however, I can't "draw" shapes inside of canvas like that because my content is not static - I have a lot of complicated divs with jquery and java on them, and that seems to cause the problem. It would be easy in case of basic static content like in your fiddle. I guess changing the code structure - applying functions on those rectangles - would be possible but that would be too much of work and too advanced for me. This feature would be cool, but it's not a must at all, so I will most likely drop it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your pants, I'd start by switching the first div to SVG notation. It's not that different and there are a ton of ways to export an svg object to png.

This should get you started

```
<svg id="1" class="aaa" width="400" height="250">
     <g>
        <rect id="svg_0" height="200" width="300" y="50" x="50" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="#dddddd"/>
        <rect id="svg_1" height="50" width="100" y="75" x="80" stroke-width="5" fill="blue"/>
        <rect id="svg_2" height="50" width="100" y="120" x="210" stroke-width="5"  fill="blue"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<div id="2" class="bbb" style="position: relative; left: 250px; top: 100px; width: 50px; height: 20px; border: solid 1px; background: #cccccc; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">click</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that would be what I need, because I need interactive divs like in my fiddle. Also, I have a lot of divs and multiple pages.